# If user +1s a Google Plus page, does he "follow" the page?

Tags: google-plus

We added a +1 button that refers to our Google Plus page. When the user clicks on the +1 button, does he end up "following" the page? Or do we MUST use the follow button instead?

The reason behind this is that we wanted to track the new followers and the only button that offers a callback function is the +1 one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

+1'ing a Google+ page and adding a Google+ page to a circle are two different actions. Currently +1'ing a page will not show that pages content in the stream of the user. If you want users to see a page's content in their stream, you will have to use the follow button or the combined follow/+1 [profile badge](https://developers.google.com/+/web/badge/).

Comment: Yup, I imaged that, too bad there's no callback on the follow button/badge

Comment: There is an open feature request. Feel free to star it but do not leave "me too" comments. https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=674

Comment: Isn't the description appearing in the G+ feed of the user when they click the +1 button? Because that's not the whole page appearing in G+, but that's still important to know that the description needs to be good to attract people on your website.